# Using Nashorn Engine Inside Eclipse Plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, nashorn

I have the following snippet that I want to run inside an Eclipse plug-in:

```
String scriptEnteredByUser = "print(\"Hello World\");";
NashornScriptEngineFactory factory = new NashornScriptEngineFactory();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getScriptEngine(e -> false);
engine.eval(scriptEnteredByUser);
```

It doesn't work, but brings the following warning in Eclipse:

> Access restriction: The type 'NashornScriptEngineFactory' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar')

And the following exception at runtime:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/NashornScriptEngineFactory

I checked, the *nashorn.jar* is indead part of the JRE, so it should work. I can't use `Import-Package` either, and why would I? These are JRE classes / packages.

Possible options I found and why they don't work / shouldn't be used:

- add *nashorn.jar* to lib folder of plug-in - quick and dirty, and possibly harmful inside the OSGi context
- use only `javax.script` - not possible; see code I need to get to work
- create a wrapper bundle around the *nashorn.jar* - I have no idea what is going to happen if we have a bundle that exports JRE packages, but it's definitively not okay

What is the right way to make the Nashorn engine work in an Eclipse plug-in?

Comment: Why not use: `ScriptEngineManager man = new ScriptEngineManager(); ScriptEngine engine = man.getEngineByName("nashorn");` ?

Comment: @JornVernee Because I can't set the `ClassFilter` with that API.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that your eclipse is not running on a Virtual Machine with JDK8.

- Go to cmd and check java -version.
- Specify javahome in [Eclipse runtime options](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html): 8
- Remove/uninstall other versions of the JDK until you have only JDK 8 installed.

Comment: 1) Is of course Java 8. 2) There's still the `NoClassDefFoundError`. 3) Can't do that, since I'm a developer and need the other JDKs. And neither should our customers, so that's not an options.

Comment: Remove/uninstall other version is just an fail proof idea to make sure your eclipse is indeed running in Java 8 ... Well, I'm out of options! Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

It works when the runtime configuration specifies the System property 
`-Dosgi.parentClassloader=ext`. The property is documented in [Eclipse](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html)